# Sandbox PayPal approval link leads to dashboard instead of payment after logging in

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal REST API in sandbox mode to test payments.

I create the approval link, then redirect user to said link.

PayPal then asks for credentials which I insert as a sandbox test buyer. But after logging in, PayPal does not redirect me to complete the approval of payment, and instead straight to My Account summary from where I cannot approve the payment. However if the user was already logged in, the payment approval proceeds as expected.

**Is it the problem with how was the link created or is it a bug?**

This is the code used to create the link

```
<?php
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

class PaypalFactory
{
private const CLIENT_ID = 'yyy';
private const CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx';

private function __construct()
{
}

public static final function getContext()
{
    return new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            self::CLIENT_ID,
            self::CLIENT_SECRET
        )
    );
}

public static final function createPaymentLink(
    int $orderId,
    string $currency,
    float $totalPrice,
    float $deliveryPrice,
    string $returnUrl,
    string $cancelUrl): string
{
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer
        ->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $details = new Details();
    $details
        ->setShipping($deliveryPrice)
        ->setSubtotal($totalPrice);


    $item = new Item();
    $item
        ->setName('products and shipping')
        ->setCurrency($currency)
        ->setPrice($totalPrice)
        ->setQuantity(1);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item));


    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount
        ->setCurrency($currency)
        ->setTotal($totalPrice + $deliveryPrice)
        ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setAmount($amount)
        ->setDescription("Products from ")
        ->setInvoiceNumber($orderId);

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls
        ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
        ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment
        ->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create(PaypalFactory::getContext());
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        print $ex;
    }

    return $payment->getApprovalLink();
}

}
```

Comment: For the past week I've had very bad results with the sandbox (yet working fine in live) .... so it may very well be something broken on their end at this time (?) ... your code 'looks' ok. I don't think setting up an Experience Profile to use would help, as it sounds like the flow on their end is just going sideways. Try purging ALL cookies you have for any 'sandbox.' paypal domains.

Comment: I don't known about that, I tried chrome (which I installed exactly for this purpose) and it still did not work every time, just sometimes. But maybe the v2 api will help ?

Comment: At this time, documentation is sketchy as all heck for v2. Many examples of v2 code, mix and match items from v1, that you really don't know if v2 accepts them or not. Like the `application_context` object... under v2 docs its called `order_application_context`, but examples for v2 uses `application_context`. LOL Go figure! So, you may or may not have success with it ;) especially with the sandbox being crazy at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purging all browser cookies for paypal domains is good advice, and may help. The problem you're experiencing is probably a general sandbox issue (that won't happen in live mode), and not a problem with your code.

However, seeing your code/solution, I do have suggestions for trying some newer/better things:

1. Instead of the old PayPal-PHP-SDK for v1/payments, use the new [Checkout-PHP-SDK for v2/orders](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK)
2. Instead of *redirecting* the buyer to the approval URL, give the approval token to the Javascript code of Smart Payment Buttons, which will display an in-context window that keeps your site loaded in the background. [Here's a demo pattern](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)

Comment: After spending hours wrestling with the PHP SDK (and all the other things it does)... looking at the Checkout PHP SDK is a complete 180. I have reservations about it, but since it is "v2", its what really should be used moving forward.

Comment: sounds good to me, I'll try that and maybe problem will go away